# ' a brazen woman like you ' or 'brazen women like you'

Tags: singular-vs-plural

> 1) I really cannot imagine how **a** brazen **woman** like you **has** the courage to live;
>   2) I really cannot imagine how brazen **women** like you **have** the courage to live.

Should I use the singular “a brazen woman”? Or the plural with “women”?

Which one sounds more natural besides being linguistically correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're both pretty insulting, but one is insulting the woman you're talking to specifically, while the other is insulting all women like her in general.

Comment: I'd add that there's a difference in nuance.  "a brazen woman like you" has a ring to it that being brazen isn't common.  "brazen women like you" has a ring to it that being brazen is common enough to have a category.